# error calling php ws using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-services

i am getting error when calling webservice using javascript.
the webservice  is ok from local and from host:

for example:

runing from my local and call the webservice from localhost its ok:

```
$.ajax({ 
           url: **'http://localhost/temp/tool/trading/19-get-sellet-item%20function.php',**
           data: { 'dateFrom': fromDate, 'dateTo': toDate ,'sellerId': seller_id, 'pageNumber': pageNum} ,
           type : "GET",
           dataType: "json", 
           crossDomain: true,
           async: true, 
           success: function(data) { 
}
```

runing from my local and call to url from host its not:

```
$.ajax({ 
           **url: 'http://dropshiptools.byethost7.com/tool/trading/19-get-sellet-item%20function.php'**,
           data: { 'dateFrom': fromDate, 'dateTo': toDate ,'sellerId': seller_id, 'pageNumber': pageNum} ,
           type : "GET",
           dataType: "json", 
           crossDomain: true,
           async: true, 
           success: function(data) { 
}
```

thank for helping!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.statusText);

Comment: i get "error" text only

Comment: What is the status of the request to the PHP, 500, 404, other?

Comment: how can i print using alert?

Comment: hit F12 to open developer console and look at the network tab for status code from your browser

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dropshiptools.byethost7.com/tool/trading/19-get-sellet-item%20functi…php?dateFrom=2016-06-01&dateTo=2016-06-30&sellerId=ayelet2105&pageNumber=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.